# Installing Pip on 2.4

Tags: python, pip, python-2.x

How do I install `pip` on python 2.4? I've tried downloading the `get-pip.py` file, but it doesn't run on version 2.4 of python. Is there anyway to edit the file to run it? Or is there another download?

Comment: I know we don't always have the option of choosing our tools, but there's no way I'd bother with 2.4 today. 2.5 came out 9 years ago and 2.6 has been out 7 years. Even if you get pip working, most of the modules you'd want to use won't support 2.4. Among other things you'll not have: "with", try/except/finally in one block, exceptions as new-style classes... I'd spend a week upgrading to 2.7 before I'd spend an hour getting pip to work on 2.4.

Comment: @KirkStrauser I use 2.4 for class I have 3.x on another virtual machine, but I mainly use the 2.4 for class. Sucks having to edit everything before I turn in the work., so I just use 2.4 most of the time.

Comment: @KirkStrauser maybe your right it would probably be easier to use pip on a newer version and just edit it to work on 2.4 for class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 2.4 was supported through v1.1.

Try this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/1.1

Answer (score 1):

From the Pip Installation guide:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/

> Python 2.5 was supported through v1.3.1, and Python 2.4 was supported
>   through v1.1.