# PIP raising SyntaxError from command line

Tags: python, pip, easy-install, centos5, python-2.4

I have attempted to install PIP using the following commands:

```
sudo yum install python-setuptools
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install supervisor
```

As it installed, a number of syntax errors were raised from the second and third lines. The errors are fairly similar to that below, so for brevity I'll omit here, but let me know if having those will help. There are a lot.

When I run any `pip` command, I get `SyntaxError`s:

```
# pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 7, in ?
    sys.exit(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 236, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2097, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1830, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.4.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 208
    except PipError as exc:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am running **CentOS release 5.11 (Final)** and **Python 2.4.3 (#1, Jan  9 2013, 06:47:03)**. Note, these are managed by WHM.

I have re-installed PIP using `python get-pip.py --ignore-installed`, but get the same result.

Is this a Python version conflict? Is my version of Python too old and the syntax in the PIP scripts different? What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`except PipError as exc:` isn't a valid Python 2.4 syntax (it should be `except PipError, exc`).

I don't think `pip` is meant to work with Python 2.4. Try this question for installing PIP 1.1, which is compatible with that version of Python:

[Installing Pip on 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440799/installing-pip-on-2-4)

Comment: That's what I thought. `:(` How difficult is it to install in parallel an updated version of Python (say, 2.7) so it doesn't disrupt my Centos install (which depends heavily on Python), and be able to run `easy_install` and `pip` that way?

Comment: This link might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440799/installing-pip-on-2-4. You can try pip v 1.1. However, it is recommended to update to latest Python version, as old version libraries might not be available.

Comment: Updating Python for the system on Centos is not recommended, due to the large number of parts that rely on it. This is why I would rather use a side install of another version. I know nothing about Python, though, so that should be interesting.

Comment: Yeah, definitely try the pip v1.1, and see if it helps. You might have to uninstall any pip version already installed. I believe you can check it with pip list.

Comment: If I could run `pip` at all, that'd be FANTASTIC! I'll have to find a way to delete the directory, I suppose, or force an install over it, though, I imagine.

Answer (score 1):

As the above answer describes, you've run into version conflicts between pip and python. You're using an old version of CentOS with an old version of python 2, which makes things worse.

Updating the system environment with 'sudo pip' has a very high risk of creating version problems with system utilities. You can, for instance, break yum, and be forced to update your system with rpm commands. You need to install a recent version of python (preferably python 3) as an alternate install in /usr/local/bin or in a user directory.

Then I highly recommend using a virtual environment (https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/, or a built-in capability in python 3.5). That lets you set up your own python executable, libraries, and installed packages any way you like, without risk of affecting your entire system. It's a minor setup pain, but it makes most of the problems just vanish.